# How can I clump my turtles at random points in my model?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I want to be able to clump my agents but have the location of this clumping to change.

At the moment I can get them to clump using

```
setxy random 4 random 4
```

but that is located around the origin of the simulation space. How can I vary this so they clump at a different point for each model run?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using asking patches to do this sort of thing but you could just change your code to.

**The set the clump by hand method**

```
let clump-X random-pxcor
let clump-Y random-pycor
crt 100 ;; or however many you want to make the create-turtles in your code
  [
  ... 
  setxy (random 4 + clump-X) (random 4 + clump-Y)  
  ]
```

**The patch and sprout method**

```
  ask one-of patches
     [
     sprout 100
        [
        set xcor xcor + random 4
        set ycor ycor + random 4
        ]
     ]
```